# No audio output from my PC even though no errors are detected

Tags: windows-10, audio

I have an audio problem with my  PC. My PC is a 6 year old i7 2600k. It was working perfectly with no issues but suddenly there was no audio output. I have tried running the troubleshooter, I have tried reinstalling drivers, I have tried booting up on Ubuntu and I tried testing the speakers with another PC and they work fine. According to Windows there is no error, it shows as everything is working properly, it even detects the speakers when I plug and unplug the speakers from my AUX port.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start troubleshooting by checking which Playback device is set as default.  Navigate to Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Sound.  Look at the Playback tab.  You should see all Playback devices listed.  Make sure your speakers are connected to the port you want to use, are turned on and at a audible volume (if applicable).  You can right-click the connected devices and select "Test" to send stereo chimes to the speakers.  If you hear the chime come through the speakers, right-click that device and select "Set as Default Device" (and also you can "Set as Default Communication Device" if you intend to use the speakers for telecommunications applications like Skype).  You can also check the levels for the device with right-click > Properties > Levels tab to ensure the device output level is adequate.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, sorry for my late reply. I have done everything you have mentioned but I can't find anything out of the ordinary. Like I said Windows shows that everything seems to working fine but still no audio. I have manged to fix it by buying a cheap USB sound card. Still I would prefer to use the onboard one so I can use the front port for my headphones.

Comment: @SJPunk - Hmm, well if your speakers work with exactly the same hardware setup when you boot into Ubuntu, the problem has to be within Windows then.  My only other suggestion would be to see if you have an audio manager app made by your internal sound card manufacturer (e.g. Realtek Sound Manager, etc.) and check the settings there instead of the Windows sound dialog.